# Close this popup by clicking away from it

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I have been trying unsuccessfully to find a way to close this popup, by clicking away from it. As of now it only closes if you click it directly.

Thank you in advance for you assistance.

HTML

```
    <h2>Popup</h2>
    <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
    </div>
```

Java Script

```
    <script>
    // When the user clicks on div, open the popup
    function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
    </script>
```

CSS

```
    /* Popup container - can be anything you want */
    .popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    }

    /* The actual popup */
    .popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
    }

    /* Popup arrow */
    .popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    /* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
    .popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Whihc one is your popup. Does not make sense!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your popup have a div container with #popup-container

```
document.querySelector(":not(#popup-container)").addEventListener(function(event){
  popup.classList.remove("show")
})
```

**UPDATE**

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  e.stopImmediatePropagation()
  if(!popup.classList.contains('show')){
      popup.classList.add("show");
      document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(ele) {
      ele.addEventListener('click', myFunction)
  })
  }
  else{
    popup.classList.remove("show");
    document.querySelectorAll("*").forEach(function(ele) {
      ele.removeEventListener('click', myFunction)
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}


/* Popup arrow */

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me to toggle the popup!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a newb, could you show me your solution in a snippet so that I can follow exactly your advice? Thanks Kinji. R

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to add the listener to the document, then if the click does not originate from any popup children then toggle (or do whatever you need)

```js
var popup = document.getElementById('popup');
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  var parent;
  if(!(parent = e.target.closest('#popup'))){
    popup.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```css
/* Popup container - can be anything you want */
    .popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    
     visibility: hidden;
     opacity: 0;
    }

    /* The actual popup */
    .popup .popuptext {
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
    }

    /* Popup arrow */
    .popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    /* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */
    .popup.show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
    }
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>
    <div class="popup show" id="popup">Click me to toggle the popup!
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Gacci for your input. It appears your solution causes the popup to appear when any part of the page is clicked? Solved one issue but I think we created another issue?

Comment: This is just an example to point you in the direction. Your example lacks of of goal. There is no clear direction of what you want to achieve! From there is easy to do whatever you want! What is the behavior you want

Comment: Changed it to appear on load and then disappear when click anywhere that is not the popup itself!